How to detect (and follow) OS dark mode with wolfram language?
I intend to use the DarkMode resource function to switch to and from dark mode
in accordance with the appearance of Windows overall.
This detection can be achieved in C#,
but I have no idea how to do the same in the wolfram language.
I believe the same is relevant for Linux and MacOS, though I don't personally use the GUI of these OS'es.
My current attempt heavily depend on resource functions and external shell calls:
(* ResourceFunction["WindowsSystemData"]["registry"] *)
regq = " reg query HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Themes\\Personalize\\ /v AppsUseLightTheme";
ResourceFunction["SystemShellRun"][regq]["StandardOutput"] // StringSplit // Last // 
  Interpreter["HexInteger"] // Interpreter["Boolean"] // Not

In which the shell call evaluated to
(* intermediate return *)
"\r\nHKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Themes\\Personalize\r\n    AppsUseLightTheme    REG_DWORD    0x0\r\n\r\n"

This however seems awkward to me, and is not an at all portable approach.
I hope this idea finally can be made into an Automatic for ResourceFunction["DarkMode"]; my furthur attempt would be to add this into the global variables of the main loop, so that theme change happens automatically.
